# Is there any setting that indicate curl_multi_exec limits?

Tags: php, curl-multi

I not sure is there a [configuration or setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php)
indicate maximum curl can execute in [curl_multi_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php)

Logically, you can stackup as many as you want to,
with the expenses of CPU usage, and network bandwidth.

Any insiders tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any, have to tweak the script to cut off at 100 curls for one curl_multi_exec